# Получить цепочку редиректов

Tags: redirect, curl

Здравствуйте.
Есть URL, после перехода по которому происходит 3-5 редиректов. Как получать список переходов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обрабатывать переходы самостоятельно.

1. Отключить `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`
2. Включить `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`
3. Включить `CURLOPT_HEADER`

При получении ответа смотреть что пришло в `Location:` заголовков если поймали редирект (301/302 etc), и, если надо, повторять запрос по этому значению до победного.

Comment: @klopp, спасибо за ответ. Примерно так и сделал. Может еще кому помогут подсказки:
1. В принципе FOLLOWLOCATION можно оставить, тогда в заголовках можно увидеть сразу все редиректы. Но мне до определенного урла нужно было редиректить, поэтому даже экономнее получилось.  
2. Еще можно включить CURLOPT_NOBODY, т.к. тело ответа мне не надо было.